How to add only role validation on web api with .net 7?
my first question here:
I have many APIs with JWT and one Identity server 3, so today everything works fine, we duplicated the code in these APIs and they validate the JWT token with the identity server, the default flow.
But since we are using Azure APIM, i thought "why not use the gateway to check if the token is valid before calling the API (it's a web app on azure)". Ok, adding the JWT validation on APIM was pretty easy, i also added a few public routes there. Now here is my problem, how can I validate only the roles at the API level? There are more than 60 roles, and hundred of routes, I don`t want to do it at Gateway level, i prefer to do it at API level, but i do not want to validate the JWT at API level, only if the token contains the correct role for that route, is it possible?
I want to check only the role at the API level, I did a few tests, but no luck.
